# How to return from function and store value on stack without overwriting return address?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, calling-convention, irvine32

I'm working with 32 bit MASM assembly, using the Irvine32. I recently learned how to access values from the stack within a function using EBP/ESP, but my program requires my function's output to be stored at the top of the stack upon return (Which I assume means, store the value 2nd to the top of the stack, and after the return, the value will be on top).

I am very lost as to how to solve this issue from here most effectively. I've been looking into different solutions, but am not sure of how to approach the problem.

I have thought of pushing the value on top of the stack, and swapping the values by temporarily storing them, but when I tried to implement that, it did not work, and I believe it may be an overly complicated solution to a simple problem.

```
main PROC   
    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, 0
    mov edx, 0
    push OFFSET aVal
    push OFFSET bVal
    push OFFSET cVal
    call testFunc
    pop eax ; Ideally, this would be the same EAX value as the function below, but I don't know how to store it 
            ; on the stack from the function below without overriding the return value
    call WriteInt
    
   
exit
main ENDP

testFunc PROC
    push esi
    mov esi, esp
    mov eax,[esi + 16]
    add eax,[esi + 12]
    sub eax,[esi + 8]
    pop esi
    ret
    
testFunc endp
```

I'm aware I'm using the ESI register when convention dictates I should be using a different one, but my professor requires that as well.

Comment: *my program requires my function's output to be stored at the top of the stack upon return* That calling convention is *terrible* for efficiency (because you can't do that efficiently without copying the return address), don't do that.  Return in EAX like a normal person and let the caller store wherever it wants, including pushing the result.  Replacing your return address with the return value is just horrible.

Comment: That is a bad idea, but nothing stops you from addressing `[esp+8]` assuming the caller allocated a slot for it. You already pass 3 arguments and nobody seems to free those.

Comment: @Peter I think by "upon return" he means at the instruction after the call, i.e. after returning.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Yes, that's what I was assuming.  But I hadn't considered requiring the caller to allocate that space above the return address; that makes the problem into a non-problem (which Jester noticed by reading the question more carefully than I did).  I was assuming that `call foo` was supposed to be like `push return_value` from the caller's perspective, returning with ESP modified and the retval at the *new* top of stack.  Not just replacing the first stack arg with a return value.

Comment: In [my sources](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/symsnip/file/9c232415d568/binsrch.asm#l360) I have several functions that use a `push` to reserve a stack slot before calling a function, but do not intend to initialise that slot to any particular value. I do this precisely so as to alllow writing to the slots that will be on the top of the stack after the function returns. In [one case](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldos/file/ede05223b42e/init.asm#l340) I do nearly the opposite: Fixing a stack with "too many" slots in use, re-arranging it to go on afterwards.